# Swift - Can't get back to my homepage once I clicked on Save button

Tags: ios, swift

I'm starting working with Xcode and Swift and I'm now stuck. I did as I learned doing the Apple tutorial on the net, but my problem is that I can't get back to my home page once I saved an item.

I have two views with their controllers: my homepage and my new item page.
I have a navigation controller between them, and I try to go from homepage to newItem page with a button (not a buttonbar). This is working.

I have my segue setup and my prepare function into my newItem page, but once I filled all the required fields, my Save button is enable, but nothing happen when I click on it, and nothing is written as output to help me.

Here are my prepare and unwind function (into homePage):

```
//MARK: Navigation
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
        case "AddLending":
            os_log("Adding a new lending.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

        case "ShowItems":
            guard segue.destination is NewLendingViewController else {
                fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
            }

            /*guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
            }

            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }

            let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal*/

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected segue identifier: \(segue.identifier)")
        }
    }

    //MARK: Actions
    // This function is dealing with calling back the homePage once a lending has been created
    @IBAction func unwindToHomePage(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? NewLendingViewController, let lending = sourceViewController.lending {

            money += lending.amount
            updateMoneyButton()
            // Save tne lendings.
            saveLendings()
        }
    }
```

And here is my prepare function of my newItem page:

```
// MARK: - Navigation
    @IBAction func lendingCancelButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways
        let isPresentingInAddLendingMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController
        if isPresentingInAddLendingMode {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController {
            owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
        } else {
            fatalError("the NewLendingViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
        }
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        // Configure the destination view controller only when the saved button is pressed.
        guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === lendingSaveButton else {
            os_log("The saved button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return
        }
        let title = lendingTitle.text ?? ""
        guard let amount = Int(lendingAmount.text ?? "0") else {
            os_log("It seems that the amount entered is incorrect", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return
        }
        let contact = lendingContact.text ?? ""
        //let date = lendingDate.text ?? ""
        let date = formatStringToDate(date: lendingDate.text ?? "")

        // Set the lending to be passed to HomePageViewController after the unwind segue.
        lending = Lending(amount: amount, title: title, contact: contact, lendingDate: date)

    }
```

Just to tell, my Cancel button is working fine and correctly leading me back to my homepage.

Comment: Is it just me, or is your "unwindToHomepage" function not actually doing any navigation? It seems to just update the `money` amount and then call `saveLendings`. Where is the navigation supposed to be happening here? The `lendingCancelButton` is actually taking care of navigation, so I guess that's why it's working there. Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: Take a look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Comment: Hi MwcsMac, this link solved my problem, in fact my code is right, but I was missing to link my Save button with the exit part of the view in the Storyboard. You can detail this and I could mark it as solved.